# No Video after Alternate install (12.0.4.5) 4k monitor

Tags: nvidia, system-installation

The live CD doesn't work on my 4k monitor (Iiyama ProLite B2888UHSU) , I have an nVidia GTX Titan and can run the Gentoo and Manjaro live CD's without issue (3840 × 2160 correctly detected). Knoppix boots into desktop (1920x1080)

I was able to install Ubuntu using the alternative install CD in text mode, but after first boot I get no video output at all, desktop or console.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding the following to grub at the end on my kernel options

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

and then doing

```
sudo update-grub
```

I am now installing nVidia proprietary driver